# Fetch data Rowdatapacket using expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can i use loop for get single value in rowdatapacket, and right now i am getting result like

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 522, number: '111', test: 'testing' },
RowDataPacket { id: 523, number: '112', test: 'testing 2' } ]
```

Here is my code

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM test', function (err, rows, fields) 
    {
        if (err) throw err
        var id =rows[0].number;
        if(id!=req.body.id)
            {
                res.send("Data not exist");
            }
            else
                {
                    res.send(rows);
                }   
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly consider the response as an array and do things as you would for any normal array.

For example,

To get the first element do `rows[0]`.

To get the number for which the id is 523 in your test data you can do this,

```
const neededResult = rows.filter(row => row.id !== 512); // [{ id: 523, number: '112', test: 'testing 2' }]
neededResult[0].number // 112
```

Comment: how can i use loop for display all numbers

Comment: Use `map` like `const numberList =  rows.map(row => row.number)`. Now, `numberList` array will contain all the numbers.

Comment: can we use res.send two times ( for show different records ) or is there some other way ?

Comment: No, you can't use send more than once. You can do something like `res.send({ number: numberList, text: textList })` and then on frontend you can access data like `data.number` and `data.text`.

Comment: then if i want to display data in two different locations then what should i do ?

Comment: It's relative. It depends on what you're using on frontend. Ask separate question.

Comment: its simple question, how can i fetch number and text in different li dynamically ?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: i have two different <ul> and i want to fetch data in both <ul> ( number and  text field data ), so how can i do this ?

Comment: Refer my first comment. Replace number in `row.number` with `text`, you'll have text array. Then you'll be able to use them whichever way you want.